# didWriteValueForCharacteristic being called after writing withoutResponse

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

We are seeing a case where writing data without response:

```
peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: .WithoutResponse)
```

Is still getting a callback to:

```
func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
```

The error is nil and the char is the one we just wrote to (.WithoutResponse). Writing using .WithResponse also gets the callback as one would expect.

What could cause such behavior?

*iOS 9.3, iPhone 6s+, Xcode 7.3.1, iOS Central, Ti CC2640 BLE Stack 2.1.0 Peripheral*

**Update 1:**

The properties on the characteristic are: .WriteWithoutResponse, .Write, .Notify (verified via characteristic.properties)

Comment: What are the properties of the characteristic?  Does it have `WriteWithoutResponse` or `Write` or both?

Comment: Thanks for the question. I have added the answer as an update to the OP.

Comment: What Characteristic are u using? is it Notify or indications?

Answer (score 0):

It was exactly the case for me on iOS10.0 and iOS10.1 Things went back to normal on iOS10.2 beta3 released Nov'14th 2016.

More details about CoreBluetooth state machine bugs under iOS10.0 10.1 can be found here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51960